# Calling Windows Credentials in Perl Script

Tags: perl

I am working on a Perl Script where I have to pass credentials to execute the script. The credentials are stored in Windows (Local User). Is there a module within Perl, wherein I can call the credentials stored in Windows. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Currently I am hard coding the credentials inside my Perl Script and I am trying to avoid that. I am thinking of creating a Local User in Windows with those credentials and then call it withing the script.

Comment: I'm not sure what "stored in Windows (Local User)" means.

Comment: The script is running from a Windows Server. The User is a local user on the server. Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a local user's password?

Comment: That is correct. I need to get the users password and use it in my script.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get a user's password. I think it's simply not stored anywhere. I think only a hash of the password is stored.

Comment: you can look at this https://metacpan.org/pod/credsman maybe this will helps